# Why does one button work, and the other error in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a MenuButton class, which is a container for all the code and event handling of the buttons on the main menu of my game I am creating. I create two buttons, and add them both to the stage (I'm using scene2d). Whichever button I add in *last* is the button that works, but the first button does a tween sequence, then throws a NullPointer:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.act(Group.java:48)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(Stage.java:202)
at me.vynlar.HorseInvaders.Screens.MainMenuScreen.render(MainMenuScreen.java:52)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at me.vynlar.HorseInvaders.HorseInvaders.render(HorseInvaders.java:22)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:204)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:112)
```

I cannot figure out why this error is happening for the life of me. The line at the top of the exception stack is:

```
actors[i].act(delta);
```

This is in one of the scene2d classes.

Main file in question:
https://github.com/Vynlar/HorseInvaders/blob/master/HorseInvaders/src/me/vynlar/HorseInvaders/Screens/MainMenuScreen.java

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question like this today. 'render' method seems to be called before 'show' method. Put all that code (show) in your constructor instead.

Comment: I moved all the code from my show, in the MainMenuScreen class into the constructor, and nothing changed. Didn't get worse. Didn't get better.

Comment: Also the code in resize, I never use that method, you should initialize everything in your constructor. Not sure if resize is called at creation and before render

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to create a new instance of all the objects in each setScreen() call?
This way you're likely to access variables that may or may not have been initialized.

One way to keep track of instances and increase the performance of your game (I mean, you're using such an amount of memory) is to create them once and make them public or static, and in each object that you want to use them just refer to the class where you've created them.

Another tip, dont iterate over the entire actors list from one stage. If you want to make that fade action, just create a table, add the actors you want to fade, and add that table to the stage. Whenever you want them to fade, just add the action to the table. (keep one reference to the objects you might want to access after adding them to the stage).